# Google prettify code: Google prettify code not working in blogspot

Tags: blogspot, syntaxhighlighter

I am using **google prettify code** in my [blog](http://www.technologycrowds.com/2016/04/jquery-magnifier-how-to-develop-image-magnifier-using-mvc.html) to **syntax highlighting** but last few days, all of sudden it **discontinue** to work. I have included **js/css** files in my **blogspot theme**, moreover  when I hit these files link directly in to my browser it throws message error page 404. I am sharing files included in my blogspot theme here as follows:

```
 <script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shCore.js' type='text/javascript'/>   
 <script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushCpp.js' type='text/javascript'/>   
 <script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushCSharp.js' type='text/javascript'/>   
 <script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushCss.js' type='text/javascript'/>   
 <script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushDelphi.js' type='text/javascript'/>   
 <script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushJava.js' type='text/javascript'/>   
 <script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushJScript.js' type='text/javascript'/>   
 <script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushPhp.js' type='text/javascript'/>   
 <script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushPython.js' type='text/javascript'/>   
 <script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushRuby.js' type='text/javascript'/>   
 <script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushSql.js' type='text/javascript'/>   
 <script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushVb.js' type='text/javascript'/>   
 <script src='http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Scripts/shBrushXml.js' type='text/javascript'/>
```

Can anyone help me out why not working.

Comment: I am also facing same problem. Have you found any solution for this ?

Comment: yeah I got solution, I am adding below solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Google is withdrawing from his service, alternatively I added a new open sourced syntax highlighter of this [site](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/integration.html). Put below code just before end head tag  in template.

```
<!-- Syntax Highlighter Additions START -->
<link href='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shCore.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<link href='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shThemeDefault.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shCore.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushCSharp.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushCss.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushJScript.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushSql.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushXml.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script language='javascript'> 
SyntaxHighlighter.config.bloggerMode = true;
SyntaxHighlighter.config.clipboardSwf = &#39;http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/clipboard.swf&#39;;
SyntaxHighlighter.all();
</script>
<!-- Syntax Highlighter Additions END -->
```

**Csharp Code to highlight csharp code:**

```
<pre class="brush: csharp;">
function helloSyntaxHighlighter()
{
 return "hi!";
}
```

**Google Deprecated Code Prettify** Showing Link 
http://java-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/deprecated-list.html
[image]

Comment: I was using the above-mentioned code but now it is also stopped working (My blog becomes so slow). Any other idea highlight code in the blogger blog.